# Source .bashrc in zsh without printing any output

Tags: bash, zsh, configuration, output

In the past, I've used bash consistently, because it's everywhere.
But recently I started to try zsh. I don't want to give up updating my `.bashrc` fil which is rsync'ed to all my servers .
So, in my `.zshrc`, I sourced my old `.bashrc` using the command `source ~/.bashrc`.

Everything goes well, except every time I open a new terminal window with zsh.
There is a bunch of information prompts to the screen.  It looks like this:

```
pms () {
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        user="$1"
    else
        user="zen"
    fi
    python /Users/zen1/zen/pythonstudy/creation/project_manager/project_manager.py $user show "$2"
}
pmcki () {
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        user="$1"
    else
        user="zen"
    fi
    python /Users/zen1/zen/pythonstudy/creation/project_manager/project_manager.py $user check_in "$2"
}
zen1@bogon:~|⇒
```

These are function definitions in my .bashrc. They're triggered by `source ~/.bashrc` in my `.zshrc` file.

What I want is for `.zshrc` to source my `.bashrc` quietly, with all stderr and stdout output hidden.

Is it possible to do that? How?

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc > /dev/null 2>&1`  ?

Comment: @User112638726, brilliant, I saw similar stuff on the crontab task of my server... But this didn't come to my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
emulate -R ksh -c 'source ~/.bashrc'
```

This tells zsh to emulate ksh while it's loading `.bashrc`, so it'll by and large apply ksh parsing rules. Zsh doesn't have a bash emulation mode, ksh is as close as it gets. Furthermore when a function defined in `.bashrc` is executed, ksh emulation mode will be enabled during the evaluation of the function as well.

Hopefully this will solve the errors that you're getting when zsh reads your `.bashrc`. If it doesn't, it should be easy to tweak your `.bashrc` so that it works well under both shells for the most part. Make a few parts conditional, such as prompt settings and key bindings which are radically different.

```
if [[ -z $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
  bind …
  PS1=…
fi
```

If you really want to hide all output, you can redirect it to `/dev/null` (`source ~/.bashrc >/dev/null 2>&1`), but I don't recommend it: you're just hiding errors that indicate that something isn't working, that doesn't make that thing work.